# jboss-as-greeter-spring won't build

Tags: spring, jboss

I am trying to get the JBoss Developer Network greeter spring project working but it is erroring out with the following error:

`Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for javax/servlet/ServletContext`

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this working.

Comment: You are missing the `servlet-api` jar.

Comment: Eclipse says the error is coming from <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> in the spring-mvc-contect.xml file. I have  <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
in my pom.

Comment: This was fixed by modifying the pom.